# Does Gambit add hidden modifiers between rounds?

Tags: destiny-2

Often when I play Gambit, I have a superb first round where I can run fast and kill lots of enemies.

Usually in the second round, I feel like I run slower and my guns do less damage.

Is the game mode adding modifiers as the rounds progress?

Comment: The second round has stronger enemies that give more mote rewards when killed (the Drifter usually says something like "the enemies are bringing out the big guns!" to signal this).

Comment: This question has been rendered moot by changes to the game. Gambit is only a single round now, like Gambit Prime used to be.

Answer (score 1):

No, as far as I know, there are no modifiers in standard Gambit.